# iosched 2014 project in android studio

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, iosched

I have downloaded iosched 2014 project from https://github.com/google/iosched

However, I am not able to proceed further due to use of "L" preview in codebase. Is there a sanitised version of the project with the android lollipop release.